# Minecraft server on Ubuntu 16 not saving worlds on shutdown

Tags: permissions, java, minecraft

My kids and I are trying to determine the issue with Minecraft server not saving worlds on reboot.

If we log off and log back in, any progress is still present, but if I reboot the machine, the world is reset.

It seems like this might be a permissions issue as I have encountered a few with setting up the MC server, but I don't have enough MC experience to know if this is expected behavior.

Do I need to set up some type of tear-down script to save progress or is there a way to elegantly shutdown the MC server before the machine powers off?

MC 1.9.4. There is a user `minecraft` and a `systemd` service to start the server on boot that I set up based on a tutorial. Other than that, it's more or less out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the Minecraft server to actually save the world state before you shut the machine hosting it down.  The Minecraft console command for this is `save-all`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried `/save-all` and got a success message, but after reboot, any progress that was made was lost. For example, any structures build will be gone. When saving, what should be updating so I can see if any files change during the save?

Comment: Your question might be better served by a gaming SE site, or a Minecraft-specific support venue.

Comment: Your tip was helpful and got me on the right path, good enough for an answer. I ended up determining somewhere the permissions must've been wrong so I deleted the directory and started over. Made the minecraft user own everything from the start and set all permissions to 764 and now it all works. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you're up and running!